# How to assign image src= string variable in JSP?

Tags: image, jsp, web

```html
    
<%
      String fn=session.getAttribute("fn").toString();
      fn="img/"+fn;
%>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" height="17">
      </td>
      <td width="20%" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" height="17" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      </td>
      <td width="20%" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" height="17" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <img border="0" src="<%=fn%>" width="90" height="90"></td>
      <td width="20%" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" height="17">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

I am generating a QR image based on user input in a previous JSP and displaying it in the above JSP. QR generation is working fine in Eclipse(Mars) Dynamic web project. Eclipse is generating it correctly in /WebContent/img/ folder.  But I am not able to display image using the above JSP. Clearing cache, Restarting Tomcat6, Restarting eclipse and Restarting Laptop did not solve the issue. I saw following errors:

```
 SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/amruth/workspace2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Banking_With_OTP2 does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

    Jul 20, 2015 4:38:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
    Jul 20, 2015 4:38:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error getConfigured
    Jul 20, 2015 4:38:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Context [/Banking_With_OTP2] startup failed due to previous errors
    Jul 20, 2015 4:38:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
    INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/Banking_With_OTP2] has not been started
    Jul 20, 2015 4:38:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
    SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/amruth/workspace2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/temp does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem continued in eclipse. So I extracted a .war file of the project and ran it in Appache Tomcat directly. Then it ran well without any issue. This is a good practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added format to the image path string.
Your jsp code should be:

```
<%
  String fn=session.getAttribute("fn").toString();
  fn="img/"+fn+".jpg";
%>
```